# Why does while(0) not execute the code?

Tags: php, function

```
<?php  
$efFect=0; 
$find='is';
$find_len=strlen($find);
$string22 ='this is space is  function';

while ($str_position =strpos($string22,$find,$effect)){
    echo $find.'the postion in '. $str_position.'<br>';
    $efFect = $str_position + $find_len ;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you make the code cleaner, please? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is the question? What result do you get? Explanation?

Comment: you are creating an infinite loop here

Comment: @Error404 it wont create an infinite loop because of the offset he is using.

Comment: ok yaar so when the while ends? @LuckySoni i have no idea really

Comment: **$efFect** != **$effect** variables are case sensitive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 is a falsy value. You should make your check more reliable by checking if strpos actually returns false.

```
<?php  
$effect=0; // not $efFect as variables names are case sensitive in PHP
$find='is';
$find_len=strlen($find);
$string22 ='this is space is  function';

while (($str_position = strpos($string22, $find, $effect)) !== False){
    echo $find.'the postion in '. $str_position.'<br>';
    $effect = $str_position + $find_len ;
}
?>
```

From the documentation:

> Returns the position of where the needle exists relative to the beginning of the haystack string (independent of offset). Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.
>
> Returns FALSE if the needle was not found.

Someone mentioned that your code creates an infinite loop but this is not the case. `strpos` accepts an `offset` as the third parameter which you have correctly used. On each iteration the offset is incremented such that the new search will begin at the position where the last found result string ends, hence avoiding the infinite loop.

Comment: Why downvote? Reason?

Comment: thank u all it work

Comment: i change $effect  to offset